# Form Post Duplicate on Global Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am attempting to make my gravity forms form post to a Global Gateway account. I have the script run after I submit the form and it works fine but it shows as two transactions on the the transaction page. Here is a gist of the code https://gist.github.com/nunotmp/8018997

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call curl_exec() twice, one below the other. Once on line 54 and once on line 57. Suggests you're submitting twice.

Comment: Wow, stupid mistake. Thank you for catching that. I stared at it for an hour.